# Create a function that takes in arrays and loop the addition of the arrays, and sets the second array values to zero

Tags: c++, arrays, function

The question is:

> Create a 'combine_Arrays' function that takes in two pointers to arrays of the same size and a int parameter for size. Create a loop that adds the second array to the first and then sets the seconds values to zero.

My code:

```
void combine_Arrays(int* arr1, int* arr2, int size)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        arr1[j] += arr2[j];
        arr2[j] = 0;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    int my_arr[]{ 4,7,1 };
    int your_arr[]{ 1,2,7 };
    combine_Arrays(my_arr, your_arr, 3);
    cout << my_arr[0] << endl; 
    cout << my_arr[1] << endl;
    cout << my_arr[2] << endl;

    cout << your_arr[0] << endl; 
    cout << your_arr[1] << endl;
    cout << your_arr[2] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

However there is error. It said identifier "j" is undefined for this line `arr2[j] = 0;` What's wrong with it?

Comment: Missing curly brackets around for loop.

Comment: Enable warnings to not have to worry about that: [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d6706cdb58efd84b).

Comment: You are just looping `arr1[j] += arr2[j];`

Comment: Technically you are taking two pointers to `int`s, not to arrays. If you actually wanted to have pointers to arrays it would [look something like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/230a716c4b14e3cb). But I don't think that's what your instructors meant.

Comment: @nwp - no need for warnings, it's a compilation error as j is out of scope, even in your example :)

Comment: @Griffin, oh my! I am such a idiot! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below covers `arr2[j] = 0;` within the loop. `j` is a local variable to the loop and without the curly brackets only the first line is in the loop. Thus the error you are seeing. This version will work:

```
void combine_Arrays(int* arr1, int* arr2, int size)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        arr1[j] += arr2[j];
        arr2[j] = 0;
    }
}
```

Please consider using `std::vector` and the STL:

```
void combine_Arrays(std::vector<int>& a,
                    std::vector<int>& b) {
  std::transform (
    a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), a.begin(), std::plus<int>());
  std::fill(b.begin(), b.end(), 0);
}
```

Comment: The OP is assuming question is forcing you to provide a function interface with arrays. Suggesting `std::vector` is outside the scope of question.

Comment: I have given the array solution above and just made a suggestion for better strategy.

Comment: Regarding the array solution, please clarify why curly brackets are required (more than one line after for loop etc) to complete the answer.

Comment: yes sir! Will do.

Comment: ooh...sorry I am a beginner, just starting. I haven't learn vector and fill yet so I do not quite get your better strategy.